# Sql-sync issues with key length

Tags: database, drush

I'm attempting to set up a new remote website for production, and push my development database to it. I've already rsync'ed the files, and set up a new settings.php for the remote site. However, when running `drush sql-sync @local @remote`, I'm getting a `query failed` error. Manually importing the dump on the remote yields the following error:

`ERROR 1071 (42000) at line 677: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes`

Manually changing the dump to use CHARSET utf8 on the column where the key is too long fixes the issue. However, this happens in a lot of tables. Besides, not having the same charset on both sites is probably asking for issues.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1814594/583447), this is the issue with an InnoDB table. However, this is the `show create table` for one of the tables affected, on the source site:

```
cache_entity_registration_type | CREATE TABLE `cache_entity_registration_type` (
  `cid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique cache ID.',
  `data` longblob COMMENT 'A collection of data to cache.',
  `expire` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp indicating when the cache entry should expire, or 0 fo
r never.',
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp indicating when the cache entry was created.',
  `serialized` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A flag to indicate whether content is serialized (1) or not (0)
.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`),
  KEY `expire` (`expire`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC COMMENT='Cache table used to store registration_type entity r
ecords.'
```

As you can see, it's also an InnoDB table, with a primary key that's 255 characters long, with an utf8mb4 encoding. That's also longer than the maximum key length of 767 bytes of InnoDB.

What can I change on either the server or client to allow me to use sql-sync to sync between the two sites?

Answer (score 0):

I remembered I changed my existing Drupal installation to support utf8mb4 on my tables, as described here: https://www.drupal.org/project/utf8mb4_convert.

Basically, the answer is that I have to change the settings on my target server as follows:

```
In order to allow for large indexes, MySQL must be set up with the following my.cnf settings:
[mysqld]
 innodb_large_prefix=true
 innodb_file_format=barracuda
 innodb_file_per_table=true
```